# How can I shutdown thread not in use?

Tags: android, thread-safety

I am struggling with an Android app to handle things new to me. I created a thread, persistent message subscriber, in my app waiting for the messages from server in the background. When I exit my app, the thread is still working. Actually, the thread try to connect again and again when it fails to connect to server. So I want to check my app is down or stil alive, otherwise  I want to make my app send some message to the thread to stop before it goes down.

What ways would be there to do that in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot destroy. Android will only stop the thread when required. You cannot stop or destroy it.

Instead try like this: Set some flag in thread, to check when it should run and when it should stop. Like this:

```
 void run()
{
 while(bool){
   //My code 
 }
 }
```

Now in onstop of your activity
Change the bool value to `false`:

```
@Override
 protected void onStop() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onStop();
bool=false
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a simple pattern for this. you start your thread in `onResume()`, and stop it on `onPause()`.

In your thread's runnable, you have a loop like,

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (mRunning) {
      // re-try server
    }
}
```

in your activity override onResume() like,

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mRunner = new Runnable { .... );
    new Thread(mRunner).start();
}
```

override onPause() to stop the thread,

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mRunner != null) {
      mRunner.setRunning(false);
      mRunner = null;
    }
}
```

This of course stops the loop, `run()` exits, and the thread is done.

In general, you follow this pattern for any sort of listener you register or thread you start. Set it up on `onResume()`, and tear down in `onPause()`.

Comment: if you found this answer useful, please accept it by clicking on the check mark next to it on the left. this lets others identify it as the helpful solution.

Comment: I need to take more time to do this.

Comment: make a counter inside the loop.. and let the inside thread start only once.. :|

Comment: @raju that'd be reasonable defensive coding, but the above pattern prevents it from being started 2x. it depends on if you are exporting your runner as a public interface to other components in the system (that you may not be authoring yourself).

Comment: uhh, it CAN'T get started 2x, because that means onResume() is called 2x without a matching onPause(), which means android is completely broken. you are essentially saying that you are defensively coding against the android OS being broken? and this answer gets unaccepted for that nonsense?